# Why does AlertDialog.Builder limit the buttons / how does it work?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to make a simple two-button alert dialog without having to resort to making a separate class. AlertDialog.Builder class, which I am using to build the dialog, has three methods when it comes to adding buttons to the dialog.

```
setPositiveButton(...)
setNegativeButton(...)
setNeutralButton(...)
```

Why does the Dialog hardcode this 3-button limit? Also, why do buttons need to be set as positive, negative, or neutral? What effect does a negative button press have compared to a positive or neutral button press?

I'm clearly missing something important, but it seems like this is a bad way to handle adding buttons? Because what if I want two (or more buttons) which shouldn't really be considered as positive or negative? The dialog doesn't allow adding more than one neutral button.

Comment: You can set a customView with any layout you want if your needs are not met by positive/negative/neutral

Answer (score 0):

Positive, neutral or negative are the options for a standard alert dialog. 
If you follow the button's name to handle a positive or a negative action, the builder will set the layout following the design guidelines, and if they change with new Android versions, you will have your options always following the suggested order.

Of course you can set your OnClickListener in whatever order you prefer.

And if you need more than 3 buttons you can inflate your custom view by something like this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_custom_layout, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a limit of three buttons primarily due to the limited width of a phone's screen in portrait mode. Imagine that all buttons are laid out in a row, as is typical for an `AlertDialog`. Beyond three buttons and you start to run out of width, text becomes truncated and the user is more at risk of inadvertently pressing the wrong button. If you require more then 3 buttons you'll either need a custom dialog with more buttons, or to rethink how exactly you want to handle the user's input while keeping in mind the restrictions of the user's potential screen size.

Likewise, the reason for three limited options of positive, neutral and negative are to provide UX consistency across the operating system. Consider an alert dialog from Android 1.5:

[image: Android 1.5 dialog]

With that of Android 4.0 and 5.0:

[image: Android 4.0 dialogs]
[image]

Note how the order of the Positive and Negative buttons have been reversed. This was a deliberate design decision introduced as of the "Holo" UI in Android 3.0. By assigning a "Positive" and "Negative" button, the positions of these buttons can be changed in keeping with the UX of the user's OS version without the need for code changes within the app.

**Further reading:**

- [Why ‘Ok’ Buttons in Dialog Boxes Work Best on the Right](http://uxmovement.com/buttons/why-ok-buttons-in-dialog-boxes-work-best-on-the-right/)
- [forms - OK/Cancel on left/right?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1072/ok-cancel-on-left-right)
- [OK-Cancel or Cancel-OK? The trouble with buttons](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/ok-cancel-or-cancel-ok/)